# Ms. Pac-Man wall in canvas not working, javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Below is the javascript for my game of ms. pac-man. I am  trying to completely recreate the layout of the game and am now creating the walls.

```
ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.strokeStyle = "#FFFFFF";
      ctx.lineWidth=2;
      ctx.moveTo(rectX, rectY);
      ctx.lineTo(rectX + rectWidth - cornerRadius, rectY);
      ctx.arcTo(rectX + rectWidth, rectY, rectX + rectWidth, rectY + cornerRadius, cornerRadius);//(x1,y1,x2,y2,radius)
      ctx.lineTo(rectX + rectWidth, rectY + rectHeight);
      ctx.arc(rectX + rectWidth - cornerRadius, rectY + rectHeight + cornerRadius, minorRadius, 0*Math.PI, 1*Math.PI);
      ctx.lineTo(rectX + rectWidth - cornerRadius * 2, rectY + cornerRadius * 4);
```

Below is where the problem occurs. it is supposed to be the inner curve of my wall but it does something especially wierd(you can see in the first picture).

```
  ctx.arc(rectX + rectWidth - cornerRadius * 2, rectY + cornerRadius * 2, 5, 1.5*Math.PI,0*Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
```

the  second picture shows what it is supposed to look like.
[image]

[image]

Comment: It's been many years since I learned multiplication, but I'm pretty sure `0*Math.PI` will ***always*** be zero.

Comment: It also seems like you're missing a line to (rectX, rectY + cornerRadius * 2) before stroking?

Comment: Thank you Elliot,  if you don't have something useful to comment, don't comment anything at all. As for Andrew, I was planning on getting the corner done first before starting the next straight line.